# RoR Active Admin adding Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

This might be a very simple questions as I am just getting started with RoR and been doing as much learning through resources as possible. Basically I am using Active Admin to handle the admin portion of my application. What I am wondering about is creating a user model. I know Active Admin uses Devise for its autherzation so if run `rails generate active_admin:resource User`it should create the user model the same way as if I ran it with Devise correct?

The end goal is to have the main front end page be a login for users that are created by the admin on Active Admin (no sign up from the front end) that will lead them to the secure information like Profile, orders, what ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do (assuming that you want to separate out the idea of Admin Users versus regular users) is first generate the new devise model as you normally would:

```
rails generate devise user
```

Then create a resource to manage them within active admin

```
rails generate active_admin:resource User
```

The rest is a [standard devise integration](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) assuming the pages are outside the scope of Active Admin.

Comment: That makes sense. So add the user model in Devise, create the resource for Active Admin, then I can just never show/use the "Sign Up" portion created by Devise and only have the sign in/out. The resource in Admin would be taking care of the "signing up".